# Intermittent Unknown Source in java. Unlikely Ant Issue

Tags: java, android, ant

This is a problem that has been addressed before but not like this. In my exception trace few lines show Unknown Source, while few lines show the proper line number.

I am assuming that this is unlike the problem with ant build script where debug="true" OR debug="on" is not given because this is intermittent. So if I rule out this, what could be the other problem causing this issue and generating exception trace such as below

```
-->     at com.company.business.class1.method1(Unknown Source)
-->     at com.company.business.class1.method2(Unknown Source)
-->     at com.company.util.class2.method1(Unknown Source)
-->     at com.company.util.class2.method2(Unknown Source)
-->     at com.company.util.class3.method1(class3.java:1039)
-->     at com.company.util.class4.method1(class4.java:17)
-->     at com.company.util.class5.method1(class5.java:52)
-->     at com.company.util.class5.method2$000(class5.java:11)
-->     at com.company.util.class5$1.method3(class5.java:21)
-->     at com.company.util.class6.method1(class6.java:107)
-->     at com.company.util.class5.method4(class5.java:26)
-->     at com.company.util.class5.main(class5.java:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this can happen in a build process where no cleanup is done. 
e.g.:

- compile without debug information
- make changes in class3->class6
- compile with debug information

Since the source is not changed in class1 & class2, these don't require new compilation. This could be checked through the time stamp when the classes were created.

Comment: Let me check this. However, this also seems unlikely. Since we have a full build each time.